# Yii Blog:Error 500 Comment and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getUrl"

Tags: blogs

i got error from yii blog development Error 500

Comment and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getUrl".

Answer (score 0):

```
actionGetUrl(){
}
```

add the term action infront of the method which is declared in the controller.

I hope you are access the controller properly.

Comment: Let me know the name of the controller and the way you hit url

Comment: one more error in managing comment:Error 403

You are not authorized to perform this action.

Comment: add that function in access rules

Comment: Error 500

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 tbl_comment.status may not be NULL

Comment: i got above error creating and displaying comment in yii blog please help me.

Comment: please  help me : how to print a reverse triangle given number in text box using php.

Comment: you are doing you assignments here..this is not how you will improve..try and think about the solution.. @BRamprasad